# Why @Autowired doesn't work return null pointer value

Tags: spring, authentication, smtp, javabeans, autowired

Here is my code. what i am doing wrong? I try to use @Autowired to get rid of 
 public static JavaMailSender emailSender = getJavaMailSender();

```
 @Component
    public class EmailServiceImpl{

        @Autowired
        public static JavaMailSender emailSender;


        @Bean
        public static JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
            JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

            mailSender.setPassword("password");

      /**/
        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't have any errors, i just got empty value

Answer (score 1):

Define below-given code in configuration class for example:

```
@Configuration
public class config{
@Bean
        public static JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
            JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

            mailSender.setPassword("password");

      /**/
        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

And then apply dependency injection in class **EmailServiceImpl** for example:

```
@Component
    public class EmailServiceImpl{

        @Autowired
        public static JavaMailSender emailSender;


        // remaining code
}
```

Comment: The method `getJavaMailSender` in class `config` should not be `static`.